# Why data is lost in SQLite database with WAL mode on when connection is not closed properly?

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, lua, wal

Problem: data is not available to `SELECT` from new connection to SQLite DB with WAL mode (Write Ahead Log) on if previous connection hasn't been closed properly. Main question is: why data is lost and is there some way to get lost transactions?

I'm trying to store data in a SQLite table with `WAL mode` on. I'll describe 3 cases: case A results in transaction loss, cases B and C - don't.

### Case A (quit app, don't close connection):

0. Open application, open Connection 1, open Connection 2 (on the same DB)
1. Begin transaction (Connection 1)
2. `INSERT`          (Connection 1)
3. End transaction   (Connection 1)
4. Repeat 5 times steps 1-3
5. `SELECT`          (Connection 1) // All data is present.
6. `SELECT`          (Connection 2) // All data is present.
7. **Close application (without closing Connection 1)**
8. Open application, open Connection 3
9. `SELECT`          (Connection 3) // **Some data is lost** - select could return 2 out of 5 inserted transactions, for example. Or 0 out of 5 transactions. Totally random.

### Case B (close connection before quit app):

0. Open application, open Connection 1, open Connection 2 (on the same DB)
1. Begin transaction (Connection 1)
2. `INSERT`          (Connection 1)
3. End transaction   (Connection 1)
4. Repeat 5 times steps 1-3
5. `SELECT`          (Connection 1) // All data is present.
6. `SELECT`          (Connection 2) // All data is present.
7. **Close Connection 1**
8. Close application
9. Open application, open Connection 3
10. `SELECT`          (Connection 3) // **All data is present.**

### Case C (perform checkpoint before close app + don't close connection):

0. Open application, open Connection 1, open Connection 2 (on the same DB)
1. Begin transaction (Connection 1)
2. `INSERT`          (Connection 1)
3. End transaction   (Connection 1)
4. Repeat 5 times steps 1-3
5. `SELECT`          (Connection 1) // All data is present.
6. `SELECT`          (Connection 2) // All data is present.
7. **Perform WAL checkpoint**
8. Close application (without closing Connection 1)
9. Open application, open Connection 3
10. `SELECT`          (Connection 3) // **All data is present.**

To sum up, when i `SELECT` from the table before closing app, all data is present, but after incorrect closing of the application (for example if app crashed) some of the data i inserted is missing. However if i perform checkpoint **before** closing the app (or close connection before closing app)- all the data is available.

Extra info:

1. If i perform checkpoint **after** re-opening app (Case A), transactions don't appear (don't proceed from journal to main db file).
2. WAL hook: i've registered callback using `sqlite3_wal_hook` to check whether transactions are actually commited to WAL-journal file and it shows that pages being successfully written to the log file.
3. WAL file: i've tried to look into `-wal` file using Device File Explorer in Android Studio or by copying it to external storage from internal storage (/data/data/com.package.my/files) and most of the time it is either empty or doesn't exist.
4. Threadsafe: i've tried to turn on SERIALIZED threadsafe mode by using SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX flag when opening DB:

`sqlite3_open_v2(db_name.c_str(), &handle, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, nullptr);`

It didn't make any difference. However, it lead to problems with reading from 2nd connection, so i use `sqlite3_open` without `SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX`.

Stack: android 7 - JNI - c++ 11 - sqlite 3.27.2

### UPD. Tried `PRAGMA synchronous = EXTRA` and `FULL` as suggested by @bwt - didn't help.

Code:

```
int wal_hook(void* userdata, sqlite3* handle, const char* dbFilename, int nPages){

    char* pChar;
    pChar = (char*)userdata; // "test"

    printf("Hello hook");
    return SQLITE_OK;
}

// DB init (executed once on app start)
void initDB() 
    int32 rc = sqlite3_open(db_name.c_str(), &handle); // rc = 0

    // check threadsafe mode
    int stResult = sqlite3_threadsafe(); // stResult = 1

    // register WAL hook
    char* pointerContext = new char[4]();
    pointerContext[0] = 't';
    pointerContext[1] = 'e';
    pointerContext[2] = 's';
    pointerContext[3] = 't';
    sqlite3_wal_hook(handle, wal_hook, pointerContext);

    // turn WAL mode on
    int32 rcWAL = sqlite3_exec(handle, "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;", processResults, &result, &errMsg); // rcWAL = 0
}

// close connection
int32 close() {
    return sqlite3_close(handle);
}

// WAL checkpoint
sqlite3_exec(handle, "pragma wal_checkpoint;", processResults, &result, &errMsg);

// Insert
EventPtr persist(EventPtr obj) {
    vector<DBData*> args;
    int beginResult = sqlite3_exec(_connector->handle, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    try {
        args.push_back(&obj->eventId);
        // ... push more args

        string query = "insert into events values(?1,?2,?3,?4,?5,?6,?7,?8,?9,?10,?11,?12,?13,?14);";
        int32_t rc = _connector->executePreparedWOresult(query.c_str(),&args);
        if(rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
            int endResult = sqlite3_exec(_connector->handle, "END TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
            return obj;
        }
    } catch(...){ }
}

// SELECT
vector<EventPtr> readAll()
{
    string query = "select * from Events;";
    ResultSetPtr result= _connector->executePrepared(query.c_str(), NULL);
    vector<EventPtr> vec;
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < result->size(); i ++){
        EventPtr event(new Event);
        // init event
        vec.push_back(EventPtr(event));
    }
    return vec;
}

// executePreparedWOresult
int32 executePreparedWOresult(const string& query, vector<DBData*> *args){
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    cout << query ;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle, query.c_str(), query.size(), &stmt, NULL);

    for(uint32 i = 0;args && i < args->size(); i ++){
        switch(args->at(i)->getType()){
              // statement bindings (sqlite3_bind_text, etc.) 
        }
    }

    int32 rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return rc;
}

// executePrepared
ResultSetPtr executePrepared(const char *query, const vector<DBData*> *args){
    ResultSetPtr res = ResultSetPtr(new ResultSet);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int32_t rs = sqlite3_prepare_v2(handle, query, strlen(query), &stmt, NULL);

    for(uint32 i = 0;args && i < args->size(); i ++){
        switch(args->at(i)->getType()){
              // statement bindings (sqlite3_bind_text, etc.) 
        }
    }
    int32 count = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
    int32 rc;
    ResultRow row;
    int32 rows = 0;
    while((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW){
         rows ++;
         for(int32 i = 0; i < count; i++){
              // multiple row.push_back-s for all columns
         }
         res->push_back(row);
         row.clear();
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return res;
}

// LUA parts: --------------------------------------------------------------


// 1.

local query = [[ SELECT val from Parameters WHERE name = "column_name"]]
local period = 0
for row in db:nrows(query) do 
    if row["val"] ~= nil then
        period = row["val"]
    end
end

// 2.

local table = {}
if json ~= nil then
    table["event_id"] = in_json["event_id"]
    local query = [[ SELECT * FROM Events WHERE event_id = "%s" ]]
    query = string.format(query, table["event_id"])    
    for row in db:nrows(query) do
        table = row
    end
else
    json = {}
    local query = [[ SELECT * FROM Events order by created DESC LIMIT 1; ]]
    for row in db:nrows(query) do
        table = row
    end
end

// 3.

function getRow(con, sql)
    local iRow = nil
    for a in con:nrows(sql) do
        iRow = a
    end
    return iRow
end
local termRow = getRow(db,[[SELECT value FROM parameters WHERE name='column_name']])

// 4.

local stmt = db:prepare("SELECT value FROM parameters WHERE name='column_name'")
local cnt = 0
for row in stmt:nrows() do
    cnt = cnt + 1
end
stmt:finalize() 

// 5.

local param = "N"
for Parameter in db_transport:nrows([[SELECT val FROM Parameters WHERE name = 'param']]) do  
    param = SParameter["val"]
end
```

Comment: Where do you commit a transaction?

Comment: Does `PRAGMA synchronous = EXTRA` help ? It changes how [the journal file is synced](https://sqlite.org/wal.html#performance_considerations)

Comment: @Shawn

in persist():

sqlite3_exec(_connector->handle, "END TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);


I've made mistake while posting code sample (now it's fixed)

Comment: @bwt tried your suggestion `PRAGMA syncrounous=EXTRA` - didn't help, unfortunately

Comment: well, this is what I expected (`PRAGMA synchronous = FULL;` is supposed to help against power loss, not application crash) but just to be sure : it's `synchronous` (not `syncrounous` nor `synchrounous `, typo makes the pragma silently ignored)

Comment: @bwt thanks for elaboration, i double-checked it to be `"PRAGMA synchronous=FULL;"`  or `"PRAGMA synchronous=EXTRA;"`. There was indeed a typo in my UPD in the post, which i've edited by now.

Is there something like that but for application crash?

Comment: Thats perculiar, I used SQLite also with non proper close of the connections or checkpointing, and the data was there as expected. With unchanged DB file but increasing WAL file and everything. On Windows and Linux. I suspect delayed file writes of android.

Comment: @Superlokkus could you please tell more about "delayed file writes of android"? I have quickly googled it - didn't find anything related so far. Is it a common Android problem? How can i address it to find out more?

Comment: Well Sqlite pretty much relies on the file/memory APIs of the used operating system. Usally all database software has the problem that altough I says the OS to write something, it can not make sure the OS or the driver and hardware acutally did so. 
But I have another thing as I read the documentation: Try the [pramga sychronous extra](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) and [locking mode exclusive](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#noshm) which according to docs solves WAL problems on restricted plattforms

Comment: @Superlokkus thanks for the suggestion! i'll sheck `pragma synchronous=EXTRA` + locking mode exclusive and come back with results

Comment: Wait a second `sqlite3_wal_hook(handle, wal_hook, pointerContext);` and I don't see where `wal_hook` is coming from and the hook. Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I suspect the problem might be already there since "If the callback returns SQLITE_ROW or SQLITE_DONE, or if it returns a value that does not correspond to any valid SQLite error code, the results are undefined."

Comment: @Superlokkus i've added the `wal_hook` code. It returns SQLITE_OK, i followed recomendations from the documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/wal_hook.html

Comment: Please also add the definitions and the overall code how you call you snippets includings headers. Of course now would be a good time to minimalize the code, as in the article I linked you.

Comment: @Superlokkus i've tested `PRAGMA synchronous=EXTRA;` + `PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;` - it didn't help. I composed a minimal reproducible example as a separate project (took all DB code from main project needed to reproduce the case). And unfortunately i can't reproduce my problem using that snippet. Actually it is very confusing: not only transactions all present using sample project, but my WAL file always exists and is not empty. So i'm confused, how to proceed with my problem and which part of the original project causez it. I suppose it's all about WAL file that keeps disappearing

Comment: Just use the original code where you can reproduce the problem and start gradually changing that to code the one where it works without the problem. You can start with whole blocks at the start and at the it it often comes down to one line, see half split method.

Comment: @Superlokkus After hours of research, i've narrowed problem down to lua-scripts. There are database interactions in some of my lua-scripts. And some particular of them make WAL file to disappear. I've added 5 listings that produce the problem to the original post (LUA parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to the fact that I used two different instances of SQLite.

1. static libsqlite3 (3.27.2) used by C++
2. static lsqlite3 (lsqlite3complete) used by Lua that internally uses sqlite 3.24.0

More detailed explanation why it is bad idea is listed here: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#multiple_copies_of_sqlite_linked_into_the_same_application

Solution:
Using dynamic libsqlite3.so on C++ side and dynamic lsqlite3.so that is linked to dynamic libsqlite3.so and liblua.so. That makes possible using the same instance of sqlite3 library on C++ and Lua sides.

After a discussion with a LuaSQLite3 developer the documentation on lua.sqlite.org concerning lsqlite3complete was updated.

http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#overview